# DataGrid Sorting doesn`t work

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid, styles

I have MainWindow.xaml with DataGrid

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Style="{StaticResource superDataGrid}" Sorting="DataGrid_Sorting_1"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.cs with handler

```
    private void DataGrid_Sorting_1(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        //handle stuff......
    }
```

And Style.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid" x:Key="superDataGrid">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding DataGrid.ItemsSource}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So after applying "superDataGrid" style event handler DataGrid_Sorting_1 doesn`t work(calls) anymore. I think that ControlTemplate override parent events handlers.

How can i set parent Sorting event handler to Style.ControlTemplate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Sorting' event raises by DataGrid that contains in your Style but not by DataGrid where the Style applied.
Just add 'Sorting' event handler to DataGrid that in your Style and it should work.